# Excel formula repeating and replacing text in countif

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I would like to know how I can perform a few actions on excel if you can help. I couldn't find a simple answer for this.

For example, A1 has a name, New York, and A2 and A3 have a formula that includes finding "New York" in the cells and performing a calculation.

A2=(Countifs(Raw!C:C,"New York"))/Raw!$F$2

A3=1-((countifs(Raw!C:C,"New York"))/Raw!$F$2

B1 has Chicago, and I would like to copy the same formulas for New York, but replace The name in the formula for Chicago, and so on, for another 300 cities. I can do that manually by replacing the names of the cities in the formula, but I often have to do this and wanted to find an automated way to do one and the rest to be done automatically for all cells.

I recorded a macro and it seems to copy the name "New York" instead of the cell and I can't make this action repeat for the next 300 values.

Does that make sense? I'm sure there's an easy way.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Max Will,, better [edit] your post and share some sample data along with expected out put, help us to fix it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A1 contains the text "New York", then you can use

in A2

```
=(Countifs(Raw!C:C,A1))/Raw!$F$2
```

in A3

```
=1-((countifs(Raw!C:C,A1))/Raw!$F$2
```

You can then copy the formulas in A2 and A3 to the right.

You may want to change the references to `Raw!C:C` to be absolute, so they don't change when the formula is copied, so maybe

in A2

```
=(Countifs(Raw!$C:$C,A1))/Raw!$F$2
```

in A3

```
=1-((countifs(Raw!$C:$C,A1))/Raw!$F$2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For some reason, that escaped me. Much appreciated.